# how to get remove blocking the device in for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have table view in  that click any i am displaying data in overlay view (overlay contain scroll view i adding near about 30 components like label , text View for each page )with near about with 20 pages 
My code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
    _scrollViewOverlay = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 103, 292, 273)];
    _scrollViewOverlay.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _scrollViewOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor  colorWithRed:10.0f/255.0 green:132.0f/255.0f blue:217.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    _scrollViewOverlay.delegate=self;
    [_viewOverlay addSubview:_scrollViewOverlay];
    [_scrollViewOverlay release];
    for(int iCount = 0;iCount<[_arrayDeatil count];iCount++)
    {
         //here  i am adding 8 label and 4 textFields to _scrollViewOverlay for each page 
    }
```

Now problem is that In Device its getting block near about 10 secs.how can i over come this problem please help me...

Comment: Running this basic line of code in different thread than UIThread can be one quick solution.

Comment: Not really, as the code following would most likely rely on it. Plus this is all UI code, UI code can NOT be run in the background in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a similar approach to UITableView. You need to only load into memory what is necessary for what you have on screen, and potentially a couple off screen to ease scrolling. You'll likely want to implement a reuse queue as well, exactly as done in UITableView.

Comment: It is quite involved. I would say give it a shot and come back with specific questions.

Comment: @Narayana - could you, in fact, use a table view?

Comment: I've seen some people who apply a rotation to a tableview, and then the inverse rotation to all the cells. In essence giving them a horizontal table view.